# twitter bootstrap 'hero' example 'jumps' when moving between 'Home' and other navbar menu item

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have recently downloaded the TB 2.0 framework. I am using the 'hero' example as a starting point. I have added links to 'empty pages' for each of the menu items on the navbar menu.

By empty page, I mean essentially the same markup as for the hero page, but with the 'hero' part removed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
      }
    </style>
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form pull-right">
              <input class="span2" type="text" placeholder="Email">
              <input class="span2" type="password" placeholder="Password">
              <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
            </form>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

      <hr>

      <footer>
        <p>&copy; Company 2012</p>
      </footer>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone explain why when I move between the 'home' link (which displays the normal hero page) to an empty page link (i.e. any other menu item link), the page jumps, i.e. the navbar menu moves to the right when moving from home -> another menu, and back to the left when moving from another menu -> home.

Why is this happening?

**[[Edit]]**

- My 'home' page is here: http://pastebin.com/byM6rcre
- An example 'other' page is here: http://pastebin.com/uFEzWyNb

Comment: Could you work up a jsFiddle?

Comment: IDK, I can try, I haven't used jsf much. IDK if I need to upload the TB files, also not sure if links will work on jsf?. I can upload the files (.zip or .tar file) somewhere though ...

Comment: @technoTarek: Please see my updated answer. I have put two pages up on pastebin. HTH.

Comment: To be honest, no, pastebin doesn't really help. jsFiddle is pretty easy to use...